# Facebook App Review, Step "Contract Signed" won't be confirmed

Tags: facebook

I got a problem with the Facebook App Review. I have to verify my Business Account, but the last step "Contract signed" won't be confirmed. I accepted the Supplemental Terms via mail and I also got a confirmation mail from Facebook that I accepted it.

Do I have to wait? Did I forget something?

Greetings Basti

Comment: Did you manage to figure this one out? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: Same issue here, just to bump this: have you found a solution

Comment: I did not receive email for Tech Provider Agreement. I am a service provider and I am suppose to receive this mail but have not receive it. I received only Supplemental Terms which I signed but still no progress in app review. Can anybody help?

Comment: @KaranBhutwala, I have the same situation. I received only Supplemental Terms about 6 hours ago. There is no second email with Tech Provider Agreement.

Comment: @AleksandrShvalev There is an open bug for the same in facebook bug report section. Many people are facing this issue. It is in 'assigned' state. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/354443052067004/

Comment: Looks like the situation got even worst. The Tech provider amendment was verified straight away after signing the agreements, but I have been waiting for 3 days for the Supplemental Terms, and the status is still Contract sent

Answer (score 1):

Searching my email I noticed there is a seperate "Supplemental Terms" to be signed.

After signing both documents the app is queued for review again - at least that's what I think is going on given the alert message they display on the report a bug page:

> We have detected that this app is currently queued for review. Please
>   be aware that reviews are undergoing heavy delays while we work to
>   clear the large backlog of submissions. We appreciate your patience,
>   and your app will be reviewed.

I was unsure if was in *really* in queue, since the App Review page does not make it clear. However, an hour or so after signing the second document the App Review page was updated:

> Your contract is under review and your status will be updated upon completion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept Supplemental Terms and Tech Provider Agreement. They are sent in 2 separate emails.

[image: Accept Supplemental Terms and Sign Tech Provider Agreement]

Once you accept and sign both agreements, your review status page will show
[image]

And then you wait for Facebook to review the signed agreements.